# Circle with half border CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to create a circle with CSS, which looks exactly like on the following picture:

[image: Wanted output]

How to make this with CSS?

Comment: That's great. Come back when you have a specific question, showing us what you've tried.

Comment: have you any HTML and CSS to share?

Comment: edit with the question

Comment: Create a circle over a semicircle.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way I can think to achieve this is to use `border-radius` on a grey `div` to make the circle and to apply black borders to two adjacent sides. You can then simply rotate the element so that the borders are on the top.

```css
div.circleThing {
    width:100px; height:100px;
    background:#666;
    border:10px solid black;
    border-radius:50%;
    border-bottom-color:#fff;
    border-right-color:#fff;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="circleThing"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible alternative if you do not want to rotate the element is to use a pseudo-element which is placed behind its parent.

Then add a linear gradient background with a cutoff to white and then you get your desired effect.

This does require a little more CSS and is a little more difficult but you get the plus side of not having rotated elements.

```css
.circle {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  background: grey;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.circle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin: -10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```